# PHP strtotime returning wrong results

Tags: php, timestamp

strtotime('3rd January,2010') returns 1230993600 in GMT+5:30.

While according to [this](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), unix timestamp 1230993600 is 3rd January,**2009**. So it's off by one year.

It's happening on PHP 5.2.6 as well as 5.2.11 .

Comment: WFM on PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.3:
`echo strtotime('3rd January,2010');` returns `1231009800`

Comment: Actually, according to that site, the unix timestamp 1230993600 is  01 / 03 / 09 @ 8:40:00am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `,` in the date string. It seems to separate date from time elements in your string, as

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('3rd January, 2010'));
```

returns

```
2009-01-03 20:10:00
```

whereas

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('3rd January 2010'));
```

(`,` removed) returns the correct date:

```
2010-01-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

When you have a comma after the month, it assumes that 2010 is military time instead of the year. If you want it to interpret 2010 as the year, omit the comma.

Comment: This should be the excepted answer. Thank you for providing an understanding of what is happening and not a "change it until it works" approach.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() is not infallible.  It is a contextual parser that tries to convert English descriptions of a date into a timestamp.  The format you are using appears to be unsuitable for proper parsing.

You can see the differences in the following examples:

```
echo strtotime('3rd January,2010')."<BR>";
echo strtotime('3 January, 2010')."<BR>";
echo strtotime('January 3rd, 2010')."<BR>";
echo strtotime('January 3, 2010')."<BR>";
```

results in:

```
1231042200
1231042200
1262505600
1262505600
```

The first two return a different timestamp than the last two.  Of the formats, the last two are more semantically (English-wise) correct, and I would try to use them instead.

**EDIT**

As other posters have noted, the comma confuses the parser about the date portion due to the order of your date tokens.

```
echo strtotime('3rd January 2010')."<BR>";
```

returns the correct timestamp for your format.

Comment: Very good answer. Just to add a bit of information: when strtotime() fails to parse the year, it uses the current year (which is 2009), just as it wasn't specified.

Comment: but why does it work with 2009? Besides, first format is perfectly valid format.