# strtotime returning unexpected results, relative timestamps

Tags: php, strtotime

I am using `strtotime` to get some relative timestamps using a string description of the amount of time to shift forward or backward, ie "+1 hour, 15 minutes", "-2 hours, 45 minutes".

This works perfectly:

```
$ds = strtotime('02/20/11 09:30:00 -1 hour');
```

However, if it is "-1 hour, 15 minutes", `strtotime` seems to be subtracting the hour, then adding the 15 minutes.

I tried it with a comma: http://codepad.org/3dq7c2GM

I came here, saw a [previous question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884509/php-strtotime-returning-wrong-results), and tried it without a comma: http://codepad.org/G8gm8E84

Still no luck.  I've tried using the relative parameter: http://codepad.org/nwZ9ZqOv  Nothing.

I found my own solution, which is pretty unintuitive, and I am not certain if I am missing something or perhaps even approaching this incorrectly.  The working version ends up being:

```
$ds = strtotime('02/20/11 09:30:00 -1 hour -15 minutes');
```

http://codepad.org/O89S3mCj

Am I missing something here?  No mention of this kind of behavior in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).  Also, is there a better way to obtain such relative timestamps using string-based durations?

**EDIT**

Edited to add the source of these strings - they are coming from the user interface via AJAX.  There are form controls that have +/- buttons to increment/decrement the duration in a display field by 15 minute intervals.  When they change, the AJAX request fires these values to the server, to be turned into epoch timestamps via `strtotime`, which are in turn stored in the database.

Comment: What date does daylight savings start?

Comment: In 2001, DST starts Sunday, March 13, ends Sunday, November 6.  I'd have a hard time seeing how this could be affected by DST - it is pretty clear what is happening.  I'd like to know why, if possible, and also if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't observed that behavior before, but maybe it's because I've always converted my intervals to minutes. I.e.,

```
$ds = strtotime('02/20/11 09:30:00 -75 minutes');
```

Comment: That had occurred to me, but the interface is giving back values in 'hours, minutes' format and it is nice to not have to monkey with the value before using it in strtotime.  That said, I'm already having to replace the comma with a hypen to get the desired output... +1 for the suggestion, but I'd rather not go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your time come from or where do you use it after? You might be able to use the MySQL Date manipulations if there's some SQL involved in this.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, rather than an answer. (As it's not an answer.) :-)

Comment: Coming from a form interface with +/- buttons that increment/decrement the value by 15 minute intervals.  I'm plucking the display value ("2 hours, 30 minutes", for example) and sending it via AJAX.  The resulting unix timestamps from this function and some other time-related math results go into the db as numeric fields.

Answer (score 0):

It makes great sense - it is a interpreter after all.

```
<?php
$ds = strtotime('02/20/11 09:30:00 -1 hour, 15 minutes');
echo $ds."\n";
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', $ds)."\n";
?>
```

that one suctracts 1 hour and adds 15 minutes to your time, so if the 15 minutes is turned into negative (as you did, it will do it as you wish)

I would never use strtotime personally - i prefer working with seconds since epoch :-)

Comment: `strtotime` is giving me the seconds since epoch that I indeed want to work with.  The user does not work with seconds since epoch... the user works with words, and that's where this string is coming from.