# formatting date in php returning current year

Tags: php, date

I'm formatting date in php. But it's returning current year.

This is my code:

```
<?php
     $date = "2 January, 2018";
     echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $date ));
?>
```

I need date format in d-m-Y format.

Comment: If you actually look at the timestsamp that's returned, you'll see that `strtotime()` treats the comma as a separator between the date and the time, so this looks like a date with no year (and it will default to the current year), but with a time of `20:18`

Comment: The issue with a comma in the string is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884509/php-strtotime-returning-wrong-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Comma

```
<?php
     $date = "2 January 2018";
     echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $date ));
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php "m" is numeric for month

Comment: @Andreas so what you want to explain

Comment: See the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the date string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php "m" is numeric of month

Comment: @Andreas - What has your comment got to do with this answer?

Comment: Yes, `m` is numeric for month...and if you take the comma out of the date string he's using, `strtotime` can parse all of it, including the year.

Comment: @mark if you remove the comma the string will be `2 January, 2018` and not `2-1-2018` as OP requests.

Comment: @Andreas - If you remove the comma, then `$date = "2 January, 2018";` will be changed to `$date = "2 January 2018";`, and the date conversion and formatting will work correctly.... as [shown here](https://3v4l.org/g9VS8)

Comment: no, if you remove the comma, `strtotime` can correctly parse the date (with the year), so the date being formatted will (correctly) have 2018 in the year. The format string 'd-m-Y' will handle the formatting.

Comment: I think @Andreas either doesn't understand the question or has never formatted a date in PHP.

Comment: Or maybe you need to learn how to properly answer a question. An answer should include (if not impossible) code how to fix the issue. Not a one liner of text. In my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas you need code to understand what "remove the comma from the date string" means?

Comment: One day you'll grow up and Lear how to answer questions and how to find then duplicates instead of doing one liners of text.

Comment: @Andreas That doesn't make your original comment any less meaningless.... it has absolutely nothing to do with `m` in the `date()` format

Comment: If "remove the comma" is an acceptable answer then would "change the placing a of the numbers" be an acceptable answer if someone wants to change from "Y-m-d" to "d-m-Y"?