# PHP Date in Alphabetically not working in Year scenario If we pass Month in Alphabetically

Tags: php

> PHP Date in Alphabetically not working in Year scenario If we pass
>   Month in Alphabetically

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("6 March, 2021"));
```

Printed Value //2020-03-06

Comment: the problem come from the ,

Comment: echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("6 March 2021"));

Comment: Same issue here, and explains that the 2021 portion of the string is interpreted as the time of day - [PHP strtotime returning wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884509/php-strtotime-returning-wrong-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to achieve it:

```
echo \DateTime::createFromFormat('j F, Y', '6 March, 2021')->format('Y-m-d');
```

The result would be: `2021-03-06`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the comma so you can do this to bypass the problem :

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace(',','',"6 March, 2021")));
```

And it's OK !